# Unix question for a date format file

Tags: shell-script, files, find, date, file-format

My filename will be in date format. eg: 20160920-A.cc1. Everyday I will getting different file, with the current date (yyyymmdd-A.cc1). I need to archival this file with the same name that is loaded and also with date and timestamp as a suffix to the file.

So my input is like  `20160920-A.cc1` and 
output that is moved to another folder and that should be like this
 `20160920-A.cc1_20160920-hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Should the suffix be the actual time and date or should it be the first part of the name repeated? For example, if you receive a file called ` 20160920-A.cc1` at 1 millisecond before midnight, you will then be processing it on 2016/09/21 and not 2016/09/20. Should the new file be called `20160920-A.cc1_20160920-hh:mm:ss` or `20160920-A.cc1_20160921-hh:mm:ss`?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to understand `date` command in detail. see `date --help`.
In your case to archive as a tarball use,

```
tar czf filename_`date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S`.tar.gz filename
```

i.e.

```
tar czf 20160920-A.cc1_`date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S`.tar.gz 20160920-A.cc1
```

colon <kbd>:</kbd> is not a valid file name hence used underscore<kbd>_</kbd> instead for hh:mm:ss.

Answer (score 1):

I think working with the date command should do the trick.

```
echo some fancy data for the file > $(date +"%Y%m%d")-A.cc1
cp $(date +"%Y%m%d")-A.cc1 <another folder path>/$(date +"%Y%m%d")-A.cc1_$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S")
```

If you want to copy the file on a different date that it was created on - use the following:

```
cp {,<another path>/}20160919-A.cc1
mv <another path>/20160919-A.cc1{,_$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S")}
```

Important thing: Use a loop if you want to copy multiple files

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tejas & Keocra.

Also I tried like below format. But it will work for the current day only.

```
mv 20160919-A.cc1 `date "+%Y%m%d"'-A.cc1_`date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S`
```

And my OutPut is:

```
20160920-A.cc1_2016_09_20_16:50:00
```

- NOTE: This will pick move the file with the current date as prefix and suffix not a specific date of the input file